# How to get full(er) table schema with HDBC

Tags: database, haskell, hdbc

HDBC beginner here. I'd like to view schemas for my tables. I know I can use `describeTable` to get the `SqlColDesc` for each table, but I'd also like to see primary and foreign keys, which `SqlColDesc` doesn't contain. Is there a way to access this information with HDBC or another Haskell interface?

Comment: `describeTable` is actually a class method, so there doesn't seem to be a particularly convenient generic way in `HDBC`.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I realized I could access the information with a query. Since I'm using the Sqlite3 backend for HDBC, the SQL is

```sql
select sql
from sqlite_master
where type="table";
```

I'll still have to extract the relevant metadata, since there don't seem to be any convenience functions for that.